# Creating continuously executing code

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, repeat

I am creating a parent-child system, with a Raspberry Pi 3 as the parent, and a series of Arduinos as the children.

The parent's primary activities are reading/writing data to the children over I2C, hosting a webserver, storing/recalling data from a Mongo DB Client, and reading/writing to GPIO.

What I'm looking for is a way to have my "main" chunk of code forever, similarly to how the code in an Arduino's loop() function works.

I know while(true) loops are a no-no, but I'm wary of using setTimeout to trigger this repeated execution because my code have very significantly different execution time depending on I2C and Database stuff.

Will a library like forever or PM2 serve me here?

Comment: If your code is purely synchronous I can't image a reason why you shouldn't use `while(true)`. You have to think about what's import: Do you want to make sure that an iteration finishes before the next one starts or is it about running the code in a specific interval?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's where things get sticky. Almost everything in the code is asynchronous (e.g. I2C reads/writes and MongoDB updates). All the asynch stuff is/will be behind if statements with some boolean logic to make sure that it's only called when it should be.

Am I just thinking about this incorrectly? Is a better way to go about this just attempting to make everything event-based?

I come from the land of PLC programming, where you have to write asynchronous code in an environment that runs synchronously, which is maybe where my confusion is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, both [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) and [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) are CLIs and made to keep processes alive by automatically restarting them when needed. If I understood that correctly, you want to repeat a chunk of code and not a process, so here's a solution on how to do that considering that you use a lot of asynchronous code:

```
async function loop() {
  /*
    Do everything you want to do in one iteration inside this function
    and use the `await` keyword to wait for Promises to resolve. If you use
    libraries that don't support Promises yet, look for a wrapper that uses
    them (often called "xy-as-promised") or use `require('util').promisify()`.
  */
}

async function startLoop() {
  while(true) await loop()
}

startLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using Bluebird to promisify everything, which is immensely helpful.

So I was under the impression that while(true) infinite loops would cause your code to lock up. What is it about using async/await in one that prevents the while(true) from causing performance issues?

Comment: If you would remove the `await` after the `while(true)`, the `loop` function would still be called repeatedly. The difference is that with `await` you can make sure that the last iteration has finished (the async function/Promise has resolved) before a new one starts, so you don't waste memory and computing power on running multiple iterations at once.

Comment: @spiteful_moose As an alternative to the `while(true) await`, you could equally write `function startLoop() { return loop().then(startLoop); }`

Answer (score 1):

@Niklas has an interesting approach using new `async`/`await` paradigm.  However, if you want to stick to "good" old fashion JS (or an armed monkey is forcing you to use it), the following should satisfy said monkey:

```
function asyncStuff() {
    // if doStuff() returns a promise, just return it.  However, I'm assuming here that doStuff() uses a error-first callback common in NodeJS.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        doStuff(function errorFirstCallback(error) {
            if(error) {
                return reject(error);
            }

            resolve();
    });
};

function loop() {
    return asyncStuff().then(loop);
}

loop();
```

Basically, you create an infinite loop using promises.  `loop()` calls `asyncStuff()` and waits for the promise to resolve.  After the promise resolves, `loop()` is called again.  No need to use `while` or ES6.

One of the interesting aspects of this snippet is you won't overflow the stack due to recursively calling `loop()`.  Cool, huh?